# React - Hot reload

Tags: reactjs

i'm new to react world and find it amazing great, currently i'm following tutorial from book pwa with react by Scott Domes

here is my problem,
when I run locally my app in localhost, nothing is display on browser, on browser console just show this but not display anything

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
>
> [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.

when I change something on my react component, for example change text on input component to trigger hot reload then my browser display the from.

> [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
>
> [WDS] App hot update...
>
> [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
>
> [HMR] Updated modules:
>
> [HMR] App is up to date.

the problem is when I deploy to firebase, I can't do anything to trigger hot reload working.
here is online my pwa react

> https://chatastrophe-335c8.firebaseapp.com/

need your suggestion since i have high spirit on react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hot reloading is meant for development purposes in order to enable rapid iteration. It requires hot-swapping of running code to work.

When you deploy to firebase, you are telling it specifically "here are the files my website uses", meaning that those are the files it's going to use.

Further, an HRM setup that works locally for dev is unlikely to work for any other scenario.

So, while there may be some very advanced way to get some form of module reloading to work with something deployed to Firebase, I encourage you to re-evaluate your need at all for HMR on Firebase.

Comment: can you suggest on my localhost, because i need to manually trigger hot reload then my browser display the from.